# Dynamically Load Model Data Using Jquery - Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

---

I have some static data I load from my model into a select drop down in my view like this:

```
MONTHLY_LEVEL = [
  'Level_1', '1',
  'Level_2', '2',
  'Level_3', '3'
]
```

I'd like to load one of two sets of information for the drop down based based on the value of another drop down's selection.  So in my model, I'd add this:

```
ANNUAL_LEVEL = [
  'Annual_Level_1', '10',
  'Annual_Level_2', '20',
  'Annual_Level_3', '30'
]
```

Then I want to toggle what I load using jQuery like:

```
$("#model_interval").change(toggle_level);
function toggle_level() {
    var interval = $("#model_interval").val();
    if (interval == 'monthly') {
       // load monthly_level
    } else if (interval == 'annual') {
       // load annual__level
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to do this.  My current select tag looks like this:

```
<%= f.select :level, options_for_select(Model::MONTHLY_LEVEL, params[:level]), {}, :class => 'select' } %>
```

I realize I'm using a helper method, and I'm not sure there is a way to write the options_for_select to pull down a different set of data from the model.  If necessary, I guess I can use a static select button and load a div, but I'd really like to keep the data in the model. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new route to my Account Controller action that would be called using jQuery based on the selection. So in my routes file, I added:

```
get '/account_level_options' => 'accounts#account_level_options'
```

Then in my controller:

```
def account_level_options
  if params[:level] == 'monthly'
    render :partial 'monthly_level_options'
  else
    render :partial 'annual_level_options'
  end
end
```

Then based on the selection in my "toggle_level" drop down, I then find the value of the selection, and passed that to my new route and reload the div with my model level options.

```
jQuery('select#toggle_level').change(function(event) {
  var select_level_div = jQuery("#level_div");
  frequency = jQuery(this).val();
  var url = "/account_level_options?level=" + frequency;
  select_level_div.load(url);
 })
```

I then load the proper model options described above based on the partial rendered which is loaded dynamically. So in my 'account_level_options' partial, I load this selection dropdown.

```
<%= f.select :level, options_for_select(Account::MONTHLY_LEVEL, params[:level]) %>
```

-- OR --

```
<%= f.select :level, options_for_select(Account::ANNUAL_LEVEL, params[:level])%>
```